# наезжает футер при открытии клавиатуры на смартфоне

Tags: css3, адаптивная-верстка

В мобильной версии сайта на странице логина, когда нажимаешь на инпут, чтобы ввести пароль, открывается клавиатура, но футер наезжает на форму и внизу появляется незаполненное пространство. У футера такие стили: position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
Как пофиксить эту проблему, чтобы футер не налазил при открытии клавиатуры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте задать `min-height` для body. Таким образом футер не должен двигаться вверх.

Answer (score 0):

если родителем футера является `body` либо элемент без `position:relative` (точнее элемент со `static`, он по-умолчанию), то футер будет позиционироваться относительно области экрана. Поэтому нужно обернуть весь контент в блок с `position:relative.`